# Is it possible to intercept Ember REST calls and/or force promise rejections?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Normally I can write error handlers for rejected promises like this:

```
user.save().then(function() {
  // do stuff
}, function(reason) {
  user.rollback();
  _this.send('showModal', 'error');
});
```

Say I have another condition that would cause the promise to fail - for example, I know ahead of time that my application has no internet connection.

I could check before saving

```
if (this.get('connection.isOffline')) {
  this.send('showModal', 'disconnected')
} else {

  // proceed as normal...
  user.save().then(function() {
}
```

but I'd prefer not to copy this code over and over.

One thought was to force all promises to reject if the app is offline, then in my rejection handlers I could check if the app is online/offline and render the appropriate message.

Alternatively, I could intercept all Ember REST calls and first check for connectivity, aborting the call and rendering a message if the app is offline.

Which method is preferred? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to extend/reopen on DS.Model and override .save() to check your connection.  You'd need to register your connection object/controller/whatever with the DI container, so that it's available in the base model, or reopened DS.Model.

I'm not sure how your connection information is determined, or at what point in your app it's available.. but whatever object determines that, I'd register it with the DI container via an application initializer and a container.register() within it.  Then in your overridden save() do a this.store.container.lookup("type:name").get('connection.isOffline') to check the connection status and do whatever.  You could this.store.container.lookup("route:application").send("offlineSaveAttempt"), or return a rejected promise via DS.PromiseObject.create() to keep things consistent but fail quicker.. or whatever.

To deal with find()'s, you'd have to extend/reopen on the store - if this is a requirement you'd probably be better off dealing with the store exclusively and not touching DS.Model.  The methods you'd be interested there would be .scheduleSave() and .find().  You'd do the same container lookup to find your connection object/controller/whatever, but just this.container.lookup()